# Are Hash Codes for structs consistent in the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#

Do structs built into the .NET Framework always return the same hash code if the contents are equal?  Specifically I am thinking about System.Drawing.Color and Size

Comment: You can expect them to behave as described in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx). Don't rely on the hashes being consistent for longer than a single program execution though - or any of the other caveats listed on that page. And of course, objects that are different can also have the same hash code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Correctly implemented `GetHashCode` returns the same value for items that are considered equal. All existing struct in .Net  indeed implement such functionality to meet that expectation.

Notes

- if hash codes are equal it does not mean objects are equal.
- there is no requirement for hash code for the same "value" to stay the same outside single execution of an application. It is unlikely for simple types like `Int32` and `Size`, but one should not rely on hash code. If you need consistent value - implement and use your own methods.

You can get more detailed discussion from Eric Lippert's [Guidelines and Rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).